# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I am trying to be able to use **react-native-chart-kit**. I installed **react-native-chart-ki**t and **react-native-svg** by npm.

react-native : "0.69.5"

After running the following command:

```
npx react-native run-android
npx react-native start
```

[image]

Comment: Have you installed `react-native-svg` and you must rebuild your app after installation?

Comment: @RohitAggarwal Yes, I have done this before.

Comment: Can you reinstall the app then? Might be some problem with cache.

Comment: @RohitAggarwal Now I cleared the cache and tried again, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you please share your project on GitHub and/or Snack to reproduce the error. This must work after `npx react-native run-android`.

Answer (score -1):

If you living in **Iran** 
Delete folder **node_module**
And **npm install** then try to more for install all packages

So install
`npm install react-native-linear-gradient --save`and use **LinearGradient** form

> import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';